# Regex matching unescaped commas in Java

Tags: java, regex

**Problem description**

I am trying to split a into separate strings, with the split() method that the String class provides. The documentation tells me that it will split around matches of the argument, which is a regular expression. The delimiter that I use is a comma, but commas can also be escaped. Escaping character that I use is a forward slash / (just to make things easier by not using a backslash, because that requires additional escaping in string literals in both Java and the regular expressions).

For instance, the input might be this:

```
a,b/,b//,c///,//,d///,
```

And the output should be:

```
a
b,b/
c/,/
d/,
```

So, the string should be split at each comma, unless that comma is preceded by an odd number of slashes (1, 3, 5, 7, ..., ∞) because that would mean that the comma is escaped.

**Possible solutions**

My initial guess would be to split it like this:

```
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<![^/](//)*/),");
```

but that is not allowed because Java doesn't allow infinite look-behind groups. I could limit the recurrence to, say, 2000 by replacing the * with {0,2000}:

```
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<![^/](//){0,2000}/),");
```

but that still puts constraints on the input. So I decided to take the recurrence out of the look-behind group, and came up with this:

```
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<!/)(?:(//)*),");
```

However, its output is the following list of strings:

```
a
b,b (the final slash is lacking in the output)
c/, (the final slash is lacking in the output)
d/,
```

Why are those slashes omitted in the 2nd and 3rd string, and how can I solve it (in Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind another method with regex, I suggest using `.matcher`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[^,/]+|/.)+");
String test = "a,b/,b//,c///,//,d///,";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll("/(.)", "$1"));
}
```

Output:

```
a
b,b/
c/,/
d/,
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/Idk6P6)

This method will match everything except the delimiting commas (kind of the reverse). The advantage is that it doesn't rely on lookarounds.

Comment: Thanks. That's an elegant solution. However, I'm unclear about the use of a non-capturing group. Is that needed in this case?

Comment: @Franklin A group is definitely needed, so that the group `[^,/]+|/.` can be repeated through `+`. Well, you could use `([^,/]+|/.)`, but that will store something in a variable, and thus require some more memory. It doesn't do much, but I prefer avoiding capture groups where possible. They tend to slow things up if you have a lot to do.

Comment: Again, thanks Jerry. That sounds plausible. :-)

Another question about that group: couldn't we just remove the inner repetition for the `[^,/]` part? (It's been a long time since I've played with regex ...)

I am accepting your answer, as it allows an 'infinite' (not actually infinite of course) number of repetitions of escaping characters.

And can you tell me anything about whether this is faster/slower compared to String.split()?

Comment: @Franklin Hmm, I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by removing the inner repetition. In the event I did get it right, you could shorten it a bit by turning things around I guess: `(?:/.|[^,])+`

Comment: @Franklin Oh, sorry. I don't know how to time functions in C# (not yet anyway ^^;) but might be worth mentioning that lookbehinds tend to be slow.

Comment: What I meant was: couldn't we just replace `(?:[^,/]+|/.)+` with `(?:[^,/]|/.)+`? Or is there a reason why it's needed?

Comment: @Franklin Oh! I believe it's a little faster with the `+` inside. Regex is greedy by default, so that you repeat `[^,/]` as much as possible first, before trying to repeat `(?:[^,/]|/.)`. This means you stay inside the inner loop as long as possible and 'break' only when special characters (the escape and the illegal `,`) are met. Again, I don't have any figures to prove it's faster but I don't think the difference should be significant.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close. To overcome lookbehind error you can use this workaround:

```
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<![^/](//){0,99}/),")
```

Comment: As with Bohemian's answer, that will break if the input has, say, 200 consecutive slashes. I am looking for a way that does not limit this number of consecutive slashes in any way.

Comment: `99` has been given as work-around you can make it a large number to cover all practical possibilities. You cannot have variable length lokbehind assertion and that restriction is by regex engine in Java. Moreover I am surprised that you chose to ignore this error in your original question.

Comment: Suggest using non-capturing group as in `(?<![^/](?://){0,99}/),`. Like this solution, clean and simple, even though it is theoretically not covering all cases with the 99 limit.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the split using a positive look behind for an *even* number of slashes preceding the comma:

```
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<=[^/](//){0,999999999}),");
```

But to display the output you want, you need a further step of removing the remaining escapes:

```
String longString = "a,b/,b//,c///,//,d///,";
String[] strings = longString.split("(?<=[^/](//){0,999999999}),");
for (String s : strings)
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("/(.)", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
a
b,b/
c/,/
d/,
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that will break if the input has, say, 20 consecutive slashes, won't it? I already mentioned that I could work around the problem by limiting the number of recurrences to 2000, but that still puts constraints on the input, even though 2000 would normally suffice.

Comment: I've changed the regex to cater for up to 1 billion slashes. Is that enough?

Comment: I see you edited your answer. {0,999999999} would be virtually infinite, but I am not sure whether that is guaranteed to work even though the Java compiler doesn't complain about it. Will it actually work for a sequence of 999999998 consecutive slashes? :)

I agree that this type of workaround is definitely usable, but I was hoping to find a solution that would not constrain this recurrence. Is it impossible in Java, or just very hard?

Comment: Yes, it will work. There is an implementation limit of `2147483647` for any quantifier (see [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)). AFAIK, this limit applies to all regex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I love regexes, but wouldn't it be easy to write the code manually here, i.e.

```
boolean escaped = false;
for(int i = 0, len = s.length() ; i < len ; i++){
    switch(s.charAt(i)){
    case "/": escaped = !escaped; break;            
    case ",": 
      if(!escaped){
         //found a segment, do something with it
      }
      //Fallthrough!
    default:
      escaped = false;
    }
}
// handle last segment
```

Comment: I already did this 'manually' indeed, but I am specifically looking for a solution with regexes now.