# Java String.split() regex for handling escaped delimeter and escaped escape characters

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String testString = "a\\,b\\\\,c,d\\\\\\,e,f\\\\g";
String[] splitedString = test.split(PATTERN_STRING);
for (String string : splitedString) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Here I have a String that encodes List of String into String where escape character is \ and delimiter is ,
 Note:(Back slashes in example doubled because of Java code) 
Backslash and comma are escaped in the original Strings and result strings are merged with comma. I need a regex to split this string into original list of strings.
So with example of string

```
"a\,b\\,c,d\\\,e,f\\g"
```

I need to get such strings:

```
"a\,b\\"
"c"
"d\\\,e"
"f\\g"
```

So the logic of split is simple: split with delimiter comma only if number of backslashes directly before it is even: 0,2,4... Only in this case this comma is delimiter. If number of backslashes before comma is odd it is escaped comma and no split should occur.

Can anybody help me with appropriate regex for this case?

**EDIT** 
I know that this regex: `(?<!\\\\),` will help to split string with commas that do not have backslashes before it. But in my case I need to split also in case number of slashes before comma is even.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Pretty similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532005/regex-matching-unescaped-commas-in-java/) asked a while back!

Comment: I'd suggest finding a library to do the parsing and not try to start from scratch with regex: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be split then you can try something like

```
split("(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\(\\\\{2}){0,1000000000}),")
```

I used `{0,1000000000}` instead of `*` because look-behind in Java needs to have obvious maximal length, and `1000000000` seems to be good enough, unless you can have more than `1000000000` continuous `\\` in your text.

---

If it doesn't have to be `split` then you can use

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\G.*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\{2})*)(,|(?<!\\G)$)",
        Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(testString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`\\G` means end of previous match, or in case this is first iteration of Matcher and there was no previous match start of the string `^`.

---

But fastest and not so hart to implement would be writing your own parser, which would use flag like `escaped` to signal that current checked character was escaped with `\`.

```
public static List<String> parse(String text) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean escaped = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == ',' && !escaped) {
            tokens.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            if (ch == '\\')
                escaped = !escaped;
            else
                escaped = false;
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }

    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        tokens.add(sb.toString());
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

---

### Demo of all approaches:

```
String testString = "a\\,b\\\\,c,d\\\\\\,e,f\\\\g";
String[] splitedString = testString
        .split("(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\(\\\\{2}){0,1000000000}),");
for (String string : splitedString) {
    System.out.println(string);
}

System.out.println("-----");
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\G.*?(?<!\\\\)(\\\\{2})*)(,|(?<!\\G)$)",
        Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(testString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

System.out.println("-----");
for (String s : parse(testString))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
a\,b\\
c
d\\\,e
f\\g
-----
a\,b\\
c
d\\\,e
f\\g
-----
a\,b\\
c
d\\\,e
f\\g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

I just implement your logic by using string operations.

```
String string = "a\\,b\\\\,c,d\\\\\\,e,f\\\\g";
String finalString = "";
for(String i : string.split(",")){
    int count = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<i.length();j++)
        if(i.charAt(j) == '\\')
            count++;    
    finalString+=(count%2==0)?","+i+"$":","+i;
} 
for(String finalAns: finalString.split("\\$")){
    System.out.println(finalAns.replaceFirst(",", ""));
}
```

Output:

```
a\,b\\
c
d\\\,e
f\\g
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you:

```
String[] splitedString = testString.split("(?<=[a-z])(\\\\{2})*,");
```

Here, it is using even number(0 is even number here) of `\` from the string followed by a `,` for the splitting delimiter.

Using `lookbehind`, it is checking whether the last character before the `\` was an alphabet or not.

Comment: This will also consume last few ``\`` before `,` you split on so first result will be `"a\,b"` instead of `"a\,b\\"`